# Ограничения в работе самодельных java приложений в Windows 10 Домашняя

Tags: java, windows-10

Я люблю разрабатывать для себя различные приложения на java. У меня Windows 10 Домашняя и java версии 1.8.151. Однако сталкиваюсь с какими-то непонятными явлениями в работе своих приложений, каких не встречалось в других ОС. В частности изменение размера окна разрешается только за определенный интервал времени, после этого изменение размера блокируется. Также расположение окна с координатами (0, 0) не соответствует левому верхнему углу, т.е. отмечено некорректное позиционирование окон. Возник закономерный вопрос, а есть ли вообще официально описанные ограничения на работу самодельных приложений? Может быть, это сказывается Домашняя версия, и мне стоило приобрести Pro версию для моих задач?

**Добавлено:**
Простая програмка, а результат на картинке ниже.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Test");
        mainWindow.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет таких ограничений. И разницы между Home и Pro в работе GUI тоже нет. Описанные симптомы выглядят, как ошибки в приложении.

Comment: Если точнее, то версия java 1.8.0_151, сборка ОС 17134.285. Также установлен Kaspersky Internet Security версии 18.0.0.405. Запуск приложения пробовал и через cmd.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы видите ошибки в программе из трех строчек, приведенной топикстартером? Я -- нет.

Comment: Я уже сильно не первый раз слышу о проблемах Java (а может и не только Java) c Windows 10. Вот буквально вчера: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439670/files-move-file-renameto-both-fail-after-many-iterations-windows-10-definit

Comment: И, кстати, я не понимаю, что такое "самодельное приложение". Я бы делил  все приложения не на "самодельные" и "несамодельные", а на содержащие ошибки и не содержащие ошибок. То есть нет и не должно быть никаких принципиальных отличий между программой, написанной вами, и программой, разработанной в недрах Microsoft или Oracle.

Comment: @m.vokhm во-первых, когда я писал комментарий, примера кода ещё не было. Во-вторых, никаких ограничений в Java или Windows, приводящим к таким эффектам, быть просто не может. Нельзя, конечно, полностью исключать, что это не баг виртуальной машины или операционной системы, но я в этом очень сомневаюсь.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Согласен, что подобных ограничений теоретически быть не должно, но практически мы неоднократно видели разные баги в разных программах, и Window и Java -- не исключение. Со многими я сталкивался лично, знаю не по-наслышке. И конкретно про баги в связке Java--Win10 я слышал не раз (правда, лично не проверял).

Comment: Проверить на другой версии OS, может быть, с другим набором обновлений или вовсе без них, с другой версией JVM. Теоретически, конечно, быть не должно, но баги бывают у всех.

Comment: Попробовал измерить mainWindow.getInsets до и после setVisible(true). Оказалось отличаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что метод JFrame.setBounds не обеспечивает до конца кроссплатформенность, ОС может игнорировать правила размещения окон. Об этом говорится в описании метода (javadoc). Я проверил на обновленной версии JDK 1.8.0_181.

> The method changes the geometry-related data. Therefore,the native windowing system may ignore such requests, or it may modifythe requested data, so that the Window object is placed and sizedin a way that corresponds closely to the desktop settings.

Кроме того, метод JFrame.getInsets до и после вызова метода JFrame.setVisible(true) возвращает различные значения.

Добиться ожидаемого поведения (расположение в левом верхнем углу) удалось следующим кодом.

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    private static JFrame mainWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainWindow = new JFrame("Test");
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        Insets insets = mainWindow.getInsets();
        mainWindow.setBounds(-insets.left, -1, 1024, 768);
    }
}
```

Comment: Кстати, может быть, просто поставить `setVisible` перед `setBounds` помогло бы. Вообще с кроссплатформенностю у GUI не всё всегда здорово. Иногда приходится изрядно поплясать с бубном и потратить нервы и время, чтобы нормально заработало и под Win, и под Mac, и под Linux.